# SOLR lost data in importing

Tags: c#, sql, solr

im using solr. im importing my data from SQL Server and i have Sp there that gives me 10000 records through a C# console application and im importing it into solr using update handler

but the problem is my doc count on solr is really weird.
it should be a Factor of 10000 but right now it's 1549988.
so it seems I've lost 12 records

I've checked my console app and log the amount of data and it is correct.

why is that? how can i find the reason?

Answer (score 0):

What is your unique identifier?

It could be possible that Solr has found some documents with the same name/content etc and considers them to be the same document and therefore will not add another copy to keep its uniqueness rule